# How to embed Tableau visualization without the use of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

I am attempting to embed a Tableau server visualization on an Angular web application and have seen in my browser debugger that the visualization is embedded with an iFrame, while I have not explicitly defined one. Due to my project's infrastructure security posture, the use of iFrames are prohibited.

I have used three different approaches so far:

1. Tableau embed API with JavaScript
2. Ngx-tableau npm package
3. tableau-authoring-viz

All three of these approaches have yielded into the use of an iFrame after rendering. Is there an approach to embedding a Tableau visualization that does not end up using an iFrame?